# how can I use "svn:global-ignores" on the server side?

Tags: svn, server, ignore, svnignore

So I know there are a lot of references on svn:ignore, but none of them is really working for me.

What I want:

Let's say I've got a repository on my Debian server in /var/lib/svn/myrepo. 
I want to add an ignore list on that specific repository which should affect every client. 
**I want to do this on the server side, not on the client side.** **I want to set this ignore list on a per repository basis.** 
So repo1 will get its on ignore list, and users committing to it won't be able to commit say *.png files, but will be able to commit *.bin files. 
In repo2 it should be completely different, where the same user would be able to commit every file type.

I am appreciative of any help.

Answer (score 2):

`svn:global-ignores` is exactly what you are looking for. The property is set on the repository, i.e. on the server side. However, it's a client that must understand and process this property -- the client must be SVN 1.8 or newer.

From SVNBook:

> `svn:global-ignores`
>
> If present on a directory, the value is a list of unversioned file patterns to be ignored by svn status and other subcommands. Unlike
>   svn:ignore these patterns apply to all unversioned subtrees under the
>   directory, not just the directory's immediate file children.

Make sure to read these docs:

- [SVNBook 1.8 | Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)
- [SVN 1.8 Release Notes | Repository Dictated Configuration](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config)

Comment: ok thanks. I `cd` into my directory and entered the following command: `svn propset svn:global-ignores *.png /var/lib/svn/myrepo`but I got the following error: `/var/lib/svn/myrepo is not a working copy`

Comment: `svn prop...` are client commands that require you to use a working copy and then commit the changes. You can use [`svnmucc`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.working-without-a-wc.html) tool to add the properties without using a local working copy.

Comment: This does not work either. Can you give the complete command for ignoring *.png files? I want to set this for my repository located in /var/lib/svn/myrepo

Comment: how can I set up those properties directly on the server?